# How do I grant permissions to all users using subinacl?

Tags: windows, cmd, administration

I can grant permission to a particular user for a service:

```
subinacl /SERVICE \\domain_name\Service_Name /GRANT=UserID1=F
```

It works fine for the `UserID1`.

Now I want this for **all users**, something like this:

```
subinacl /SERVICE \\domain_name\Service_Name /GRANT=All_Users=F
```

How can I grant permissions to all users?

Comment: Have you tried using groups? I think that's the only way to accomplish this.

Comment: S-1-5-11 Authenticated Users A group that includes all users whose identities were authenticated when they logged on. Membership is controlled by the operating system. From Oct 2001 MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Noodles to allow all users to control the service you can use  the known ID

`S-1-5-11 (Authenticated Users)`

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330

So your example would be:

`subinacl /SERVICE \\domain_name\Service_Name /GRANT=S-1-5-11=F`